# Get an error when call a method in graphql nodejs express app

Tags: node.js, graphql-js

I don't know more in qraphql. I just host my graphql api in local post.When i run it using curl, it will get an error. that "Invalid JSON data"

```
curl -s -d '{ "query": "{ AccountTransfer(["from":"asset1","to":"asset2","amount":"5"]){result } }" }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:4000/graphq
```

Please give a correct format for it.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `{ "query": "{ AccountTransfer(["from":"asset1","to":"asset2","amount":"5"]){result } }" }` is not valid JSON, not by a long shot … If you don’t know how JSON basically works, please go read up on that first.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Please give a correct JSON for this particular case if possible.